# Vim $VIMRC no longer being read; $HOME shows "%USERPROFILES%"

Tags: vim

In setting up my machine for an EdX class today, my VIM `_vimrc` is no longer being read.

The changes I made were to install Visual Studio Code and to run a `pip` command in the Anaconda prompt (`pip install -q datascience okpy`).

Now when I open a vim file, it loads a tiny window with text in 4 point Fixedsys font.

`:echo $MYVIMRC` shows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc
```

`:version` shows:

```
system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
```

`:echo $HOME` gives:

```
%USERPROFILES%
```

The vimrc in my home directory (`Users/myname/_vimrc`) is not being seen.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling vim, thinking that the Anaconda pip and VS Code installation might have knocked something awry, but that did not help.

How can I get my Vim functionality back?

Comment: `$HOME` should be `%USERPROFILE%`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting a Windows environmental variable of

```
Home = Users/myname
```

I still don't understand how this all happened to begin with, but now all is well.